# VS2017 SSIS Version Control for subversion and/or BitBucket

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ssis, version-control, tortoisesvn

**Question:** Is it possible to manage the versioning of an SSIS project/package? If yes, which tool: SVN/BitBucket, VS2017 or SQL Server?

**Context:** My employer currently uses subversion (SVN) but is moving to BitBucket. From what I can tell, SVN does not handle SSIS project/package versioning. Now, in the SSIS solution within VS2017, I can modify the project version and set the Major, Minor, and Build numbers (I have set it to 1.0.0). However, when I build the solution, the values are reset to 0 (i.e., 0.0.0). Additionally, when I deploy the the project to the Integration Services Catalog, and I query the table (see query below) the Major, Minor, and Build are set to 1.0.125. I do not understand why the project does not reflect these values.

So, it seems impossible to track other than to deploy; get the version info;  include it in the check-in comments to SVN. No?

```
SELECT *
FROM SSISDB.internal.packages
```

Comment: You can explore the `visual svn` tool. It integrates well with tortoise svn or infact any subversion. Though I myself, am looking for something as similar as how `Talend` manages repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're talking about. Version control is version control. There are things you can do with SVN that you cannot do with other source control systems, like using the ... macro expansion things `$author$` or something like that but it still versions the software.

I created a package, Package2, and explicitly assigned values to VersionComments, VersionMajor, VersionMinor. VersionBuild is an autoincrementing number based on the number of times the package is saved.

[image: package properties]

I deployed that package to both the SQL Server package store (msdb) and then deployed the project to the Integration Services Catalog (SSISDB). I then ran the following query to examine the data.

```
SELECT
    S.name
,   S.description
,   S.vermajor
,   S.verminor
,   S.verbuild
,   S.vercomments
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysssispackages AS S
WHERE
    S.name = 'Package2';

SELECT
    P.name
,   P.description
,   P.version_major
,   P.version_minor
,   P.version_build
,   P.version_comments
FROM
    SSISDB.catalog.packages AS P
WHERE
    P.name = 'Package2.dtsx';
```

As you can see in the results, the VersionBuild/VersionComments/VersionMajor/VersionMinor (and description) are all exposed as first tier elements.

[image]

These are the same values that my package recorded.

The comments indicate that a package is showing up in one place, SSISDB and not the msdb.

This relates to the design choice of Package Deployment Model versus Project Deployment Model.

Package deployment was the only option prior to SQL Server 2012. Package deployment *can* go to SQL Server and if it does, it will be found in the msdb in a table with a name starting with `syspackages` (actual name varies between 2005, 2008/r2). Otherwise, they will be on the file system somewhere. Package Deployment is still an option with the current 2017 release.

Project deployment was new in 2012 and became the default option. It addresses many of the management issues surrounding packages. Instead, projects are treated as a whole, inseverable unit instead of N SSIS packages. Projects are "compiled" into a deployable unit with a .ispac extension (a zip file with a manifest). The .ispac file is then deployed into the SSISDB, typically through the isdeploymentwizard.exe

The [Incremental Package Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017#deploy-packages-to-integration-services-server) feature still uses the Project Deployment Model<sup>*</sup> so your packages are going to be stored in the SSISDB.

The SSISDB UI exposes a Properties menu for projects that indicates name, id, description, project version and deployment date. Since that is easily viewed, I used to set the project description to `$Revision` or something like that so I could see at a glance whether the project was where I expected it to be.

[image]

This can also be derived by querying the base tables like

```
SELECT
    F.name AS FolderName
,   F.description AS FolderDescription
,   PR.name AS ProjectName
,   P.description AS ProjectDescription
,   PR.project_format_version
,   PR.deployed_by_name
,   PR.last_deployed_time
,   PR.created_time
,   PR.validation_status
,   PR.last_validation_time
,   P.name AS PackageName
,   P.description AS PackageDescription
,   P.version_major
,   P.version_minor
,   P.version_build
,   P.version_comments
FROM
    catalog.projects AS PR
    INNER JOIN
        catalog.folders AS F
        ON F.folder_id = PR.folder_id
    INNER JOIN
        catalog.packages AS P
        ON P.project_id = PR.project_id;
```

- Fun trick, the Incremental Package Deployment feature will create a project for you as it deploys into the SSISDB. So, you can get the management niceties of the Project Deployment Model while leaving your project in the package deployment model.

Comment: I see what the problem is. I right clicked on the project and set the version info there. However, you were pointing to the actual package. That clears it up for me.Thanks.

Comment: I see that the package shows up in SSISDB.catalog.packages (2nd query), but it does not show up in msdb.dbo.sysssispackages (1st query). Any ideas why and does it matter? Note: I am on SQL 2014, VS 2017. The project was deployed from VS2017 (instead of isdeploymentwizard.exe)

Comment: Beefed out the answer to address why you'll find the package in one place or the other @JWeezy

Comment: I see, you provided the table info I would expect to find the data depending on which deployment model I was using. Yes, I am aware of the differences between deployment models, but was not aware of where they were stored on the DB with respect to Package Deployment. Per Microsoft's website (see next comment), they 'introduced' Package Deployment model for allowing separate deployments of packages in the project deployment model starting in 2016. It's confusing as hell, especially when their site explicitly states the package deployment model is LEGACY.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017 @billinkc

Comment: The inseparability of the package from the project in 2012/2014 Project Deployment models is why I was looking at the versioning info at the project level as opposed to the package level. This might explain why you weren't understanding what I was talking about.